# How to use BULK COLLECT in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

How to use BULK COLLECT in PostgreSQL. I have declared like this in my code but am getting error like
*ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COLLECT"
LINE 47:     EXECUTE W_SQL BULK COLLECT*
please help me to solve this error.

```
DECLARE

   TMP_RECORD   IFSC;
   W_SQL        VARCHAR(500);
   W_IFSC       VARCHAR(50);
   W_BANK_NAME  VARCHAR(50);
   W_BRN_NAME   VARCHAR(50);
   W_CITY_NAME  VARCHAR(50);
   W_STATE_NAME VARCHAR(50);
   W_SQL_DATA   VARCHAR(500);
   
   IFSC_FETCH_OBJ ifsc_fetch_string;

W_SQL := 'SELECT IFSRID_IFS_CODE, IFSRID_BRN_NAME|| '' - '' ||IFSRID_BRN_PLACE, IFSRID_BRN_ADDR1 FROM IFSRID
            WHERE 1=1';
           
IF TRIM(P_IFSC) IS NOT NULL THEN
W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_IFS_CODE LIKE ''%' || W_IFSC || '%''';
  ELSE
 IF TRIM(P_BANK_NAME) IS NOT NULL THEN
W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_BRN_NAME LIKE ''%' || W_BANK_NAME ||
'%''';
 END IF;
END IF;
 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE W_SQL BULK COLLECT
    
      INTO IFSC_FETCH_OBJ;
    IF IFSC_FETCH_OBJ.COUNT > 0 THEN
      FOR IDX IN IFSC_FETCH_OBJ.FIRST .. IFSC_FETCH_OBJ.LAST LOOP
        TMP_RECORD.IFS_CODE      := IFSC_FETCH_OBJ(IDX).IFS_CODE;
        TMP_RECORD.IFS_BANK_NAME := IFSC_FETCH_OBJ(IDX).IFS_BANK_NAME;
        TMP_RECORD.IFS_BRN_NAME  := IFSC_FETCH_OBJ(IDX).IFS_BRN_NAME;
         RETURN NEXT TMP_RECORD;
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
```

---

Can i use count in IF condition in PostgreSQL or i have to use cardinality
IF IFSC_FETCH_OBJ.COUNT > 0 THEN
as am new to PostgreSQL please help me to solve this error

Comment: There is no bulk collect in PL/pgSQL. The closest you can get is aggregate the result into an array. If you want a better answer, you will need to provide way more details.

Comment: should i assign W_SQL to array

Comment: You can simplify that to a function that uses `returns table (...)`  and  `return query execute ...`

Comment: @KSMNOPk - you don't need bulk collect in Postgres - it has not any sense do it in Postgres because it uses different architecture

Comment: sir, how to do that

Comment: as am new to Postgresql...i dont know how to display multiple record in postgresql..In stand of bulk collect what can i use in Postgresql

Comment: Before writing some random code and praying that it works, you might want to take a look at the fine manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to "collect" a result in order to return the result of a query in Postgres.

You can declare the function to return a table, then use `return query` to return that:

You have only provided a partial definition of your function, but something like this should get you started:

```
create or replace function some_function(p_ifsc text, p_bank_name text)
  returns table (IFS_CODE text, IFS_BANK_NAME text, IFS_BRN_NAME text)
as
$$
declare
  w_sql text;
begin
  W_SQL := 'SELECT IFSRID_IFS_CODE, IFSRID_BRN_NAME|| '' - '' ||IFSRID_BRN_PLACE, IFSRID_BRN_ADDR1 FROM IFSRID
            WHERE 1=1';

  IF nullif(TRIM(P_IFSC),'') IS NOT NULL THEN
    W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_IFS_CODE LIKE ''%' || W_IFSC || '%''';
  ELSIF nullif(TRIM(P_BANK_NAME),'') IS NOT NULL THEN
    W_SQL := W_SQL || ' AND IFSRID_BRN_NAME LIKE ''%' || W_BANK_NAME || '%''';
  END IF;
  return query execute w_sql;
end;
$$
language  plpgsql;
```

Note that I had to guess the structure and data types of the result.

Comment: sir am getting like this error NOTICE:  GOT HEREW_SQL :<NULL> 
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pkg_beneficiary_fn_get_ifsc(text,text,text,text,text) line 34 at RETURN QUERY